# What is the C equivalent of Python's filter(function, iterable)?

Tags: python, c, arrays, python-2.7, lambda

I am attempting to convert the following line of Python into C. The problem is that formulation is, for me, highly complicated. cubies is an array with a length equal to 120 lowercase characters. Here is a sample:

```
fc = ""
try :
    # Pos 1
    fc += filter(lambda a : 'y' in a and 'b'  in a and 'o' in a, cubies)[0]
    fc += filter(lambda a : 'y' in a and 'o'  in a and a.count('n') == 4, cubies)[0]
    fc += filter(lambda a : 'y' in a and 'o'  in a and 'g' in a, cubies)[0]
    fc += filter(lambda a : 'y' in a and 'b'  in a and a.count('n') == 4, cubies)[0]
    fc += filter(lambda a : 'y' in a and 'g'  in a and a.count('n') == 4, cubies)[0]
    fc += filter(lambda a : 'y' in a and 'b'  in a and 'r' in a, cubies)[0]
    fc += filter(lambda a : 'y' in a and 'r'  in a and a.count('n') == 4, cubies)[0]
    fc += filter(lambda a : 'y' in a and 'r'  in a and 'g' in a, cubies)[0]
    # Pos 9
    fc += filter(lambda a : 'o' in a and 'b'  in a and a.count('n') == 4, cubies)[0]
    fc += filter(lambda a : 'o' in a and 'g'  in a and a.count('n') == 4, cubies)[0]
    fc += filter(lambda a : 'b' in a and 'r'  in a and a.count('n') == 4, cubies)[0]
    fc += filter(lambda a : 'g' in a and 'r'  in a and a.count('n') == 4, cubies)[0]
    # Pos 13
    fc += filter(lambda a : 'w' in a and 'b'  in a and 'o' in a, cubies)[0]
    fc += filter(lambda a : 'w' in a and 'o'  in a and a.count('n') == 4, cubies)[0]
    fc += filter(lambda a : 'w' in a and 'o'  in a and 'g' in a, cubies)[0]
    fc += filter(lambda a : 'w' in a and 'b'  in a and a.count('n') == 4, cubies)[0]
    fc += filter(lambda a : 'w' in a and 'g'  in a and a.count('n') == 4, cubies)[0]
    fc += filter(lambda a : 'w' in a and 'b'  in a and 'r' in a, cubies)[0]
    fc += filter(lambda a : 'w' in a and 'r'  in a and a.count('n') == 4, cubies)[0]
    fc += filter(lambda a : 'w' in a and 'r'  in a and 'g' in a, cubies)[0]
except IndexError :
    sys.exit("IndexError raised")
```

I have attempted to use several Python to C Converters, such as Cython, but they were all either to complex to use or the code they produced was too long to be practical for a C noob such as myself.

If someone could point me in the correct direction of documentation that would be helpful, or if you're feeling extremely kind, write an example function in C for me.

Comment: There's definitely a better way to do this...

Comment: By a better way, do you mean better code or better "question-asking"?

Comment: Better code. That's some really weird code right there.

Comment: If you wish to see the git repo I got it from, check it out here: [https://github.com/brownan/Rubiks-Cube-Solve](https://github.com/brownan/Rubiks-Cube-Solver)

Comment: Don't try to find "equivalents" between languages. If you need to port code, do the following: read the original code, understand the original code, meditate, align your mind with the target language, implement the code idiosyncratically in the target language.

Comment: @Hyperboreus, Ideally, I would attempt this, were it not for the fact that I have been teaching myself C on and off for the past two weeks.

Comment: I see the problem, you're trying to learn C :P

Comment: What's this code even trying to do?

Comment: I'll be sure to pass on your recommendations to him, thank you StackOverflow, you are an awesome community :') @Eric, check out the repo: [https://github.com/brownan/Rubiks-Cube-Solver]

Comment: This would be better written in python as: `next(a for a in cubies if 'y' in a and 'b' in a and 'o' in a)` rather than `filter(lambda a : 'y' in a and 'b' in a and 'o' in a, cubies)[0]`. Then it will raise `StopIteration` rather than `IndexError`.

Comment: @BenjiSparks: What exactly does `cubies` contain here? **Nevermind, found [the file](https://github.com/brownan/Rubiks-Cube-Solver/blob/master/cube_convert.py)**

Comment: I seriously suggest that it's not a wise idea for someone inexperienced in C to translate a Python program to C. In fact it's a really bad idea to do such a translation at all.

Comment: @JimBalter, I can see your point, it's certainly valid, but I have an interest in relatively low level languages, such as C, got bored of Python and have an interest in solving puzzles, so this was more of a personal venture, than anything else :).

Comment: Well, if your goal is understanding low level languages and techniques, definitely take a look at my answer.

Comment: Very intricate code, I like it! Thanks for your contribution to the post! +1 for your comment and your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it's easier to translate the python to sane python first:

```
def find_matching(pattern):
    try:
        # Find the first cube where the cubie faces are a shuffled
        # version of the search faces"
        return next(c for c in cubies if sorted(c) == sorted(pattern))

    except StopIteration:
        # next raises StopIteration if it cannot find anything
        raise ValueError("Could not find pattern {}".format(pattern))


fc = ""
# Pos 1
fc += find_matching('ybonnn')
fc += find_matching('yonnnn')
fc += find_matching('yognnn')
fc += find_matching('ybnnnn')
fc += find_matching('ygnnnn')
fc += find_matching('ybrnnn')
fc += find_matching('yrnnnn')
fc += find_matching('yrgnnn')
# Pos 9
fc += find_matching('obnnnn')
fc += find_matching('ognnnn')
fc += find_matching('brnnnn')
fc += find_matching('grnnnn')
# Pos 13
fc += find_matching('wbonnn')
fc += find_matching('wonnnn')
fc += find_matching('wognnn')
fc += find_matching('wbnnnn')
fc += find_matching('wgnnnn')
fc += find_matching('wbrnnn')
fc += find_matching('wrnnnn')
fc += find_matching('wrgnnn')
```

Now all you have to do is implement:

> Find the first cube where the cubie faces are a shuffled version of the search faces

Which is an exercise left to the reader

Comment: +1 for posting the most easily readable code on this entire page :)

Comment: @BenjiSparks: If you used underscores or spaces instead of `n`s, it'd be easier to see what's going on here

Comment: You forget/may not have noticed that the posted code isn't mine, it's from a Github repo, as mentioned above. Here is the link, the code in question is taken from a file called cube_convert.py: https://github.com/brownan/Rubiks-Cube-Solver/

Comment: You forget/may not have noticed that there's nothing to stop you changing how other parts of the code work at the same time

Comment: You assume I understood that chunk of posted code, which is why I gave you a +1 on your post

Answer (score 2):

`filter`, in Python, takes a condition (expressed as a function) and tests every element of an iterable (e.g. a list) against that condition. It returns a list containing every element that satisfies the condition.

Since this code always takes the first element of the filtered result, you can express a similar thing in C as follows:

```
char *result;
int i;

for(i=0; i<120; i++) { // where 120 is the length of the array
    if(strchr(cubies[i], 'y') && strchr(cubies[i], 'b') && strchr(cubies[i], 'o')) {
        // Condition passes, set result
        result = cubies[i];
        break;
    }
}
if(i == 120) {
    // No condition passed: throw an error
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: condition failed");
    exit(1);
}
```

Then use e.g. `sprintf` to append `result` to the `fc` string you're building.

Comment: how should I declare the array? char cubies[49] = "rrrrrrrrbbbwwwgggyyybbwwggyybbbwwwgggyyyoooooooo"; gives me a Read Access Violation error :/

Comment: `char cubies[49][7]` I think, given that the `cubies` in the original source code is a *list of strings*. Then make sure to change `120` to `49` above. (You can also use a variable for the length). Note that the final `[7]` allows your `cubies` array to store 49 *6*-letter strings, with a final (7th) null-terminator character.

Comment: How do I go about giving values to what used to be a "one dimensional array", that is now two dimensional?

Comment: @BenjiSparks: Something like `char cubies[49][7] = {"abcdef", "ghiklm", ...}`

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring to the letters corresponding to colours? But I can't see any advantage to using a two dimensional array, as I only have the six letters :/ Apologies if I'm asking stupid queries, but I really am curious

Comment: I'm basing this off the code in the GitHub. That code builds `cubies` as a list of 20 6-character strings (so it should be `char cubies[20][7]`). This is distinct from the original input string, which is a single string of 48 characters.

Comment: my mind is whizzing O.O so please forgive me for posing this most likely stupendously ignorant question, but how did you reach the value of 20?

Comment: Oh I see 20*(7-1) = 120. Very smart! Though wouldn't a +1 suffice for the null deliminator?

Comment: The code above gives me a Read Access Violation upon reaching the line with strchr(). Any clue as to why?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach. (I haven't tested or even compiled this.)

```
char* fc = NULL;
int fclen = 0;

void appendtofc(const char* str)
{
    if (!str)
        return;

    int len = strlen(str);
    fc = realloc(fc, fclen + len + 1);
    if (!fc)
        /* handle error */;
    strcpy(fc + fclen, str);
    fclen += len;
}

const char* match3(const char** arr, int n, char c1, char c2, char c3)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int needc = 7;
        for (const char* p = arr[i]; *p; p++)
        {
            if (*p == c1)
                needc &= ~1;
            else if (*p == c2)
                needc &= ~2;
            else if (*p == c3)
                needc &= ~4;

            if (!needc)
                return arr[i];
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

const char* match2plus4n(const char** arr, int n, char c1, char c2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int needc = 3, needn = 4;
        for (const char* p = arr[i]; *p; p++)
        {
            if (*p == c1)
                needc &= ~1;
            else if (*p == c2)
                needc &= ~2;

            if (*p == 'n')
                needn--;

            if (!needc && !needn)
                return arr[i];
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void appendcubies(const char** cubies, int ncubies)
{
    appendtofc(match3(cubies, ncubies, 'y', 'b', 'o'));
    appendtofc(match2plus4n(cubies, ncubies, 'y', 'o'));
    appendtofc(match3(cubies, ncubies, 'y', 'o', 'g'));
    appendtofc(match2plus4n(cubies, ncubies, 'y', 'b'));
    appendtofc(match2plus4n(cubies, ncubies, 'y', 'g'));
    appendtofc(match3(cubies, ncubies, 'y', 'b', 'r' ));
    appendtofc(match2plus4n(cubies, ncubies, 'y', 'r'));
    appendtofc(match3(cubies, ncubies, 'y', 'r' , 'g' ));
    // Pos 9
    appendtofc(match2plus4n(cubies, ncubies, 'o', 'b'));
    appendtofc(match2plus4n(cubies, ncubies, 'o', 'g'));
    appendtofc(match2plus4n(cubies, ncubies, 'b', 'r'));
    appendtofc(match2plus4n(cubies, ncubies, 'g', 'r'));
    // Pos 13
    appendtofc(match3(cubies, ncubies, 'w', 'b' , 'o' ));
    appendtofc(match2plus4n(cubies, ncubies, 'w', 'o'));
    appendtofc(match3(cubies, ncubies, 'w', 'o' , 'g' ));
    appendtofc(match2plus4n(cubies, ncubies, 'w', 'b'));
    appendtofc(match2plus4n(cubies, ncubies, 'w', 'g'));
    appendtofc(match3(cubies, ncubies, 'w', 'b' , 'r' ));
    appendtofc(match2plus4n(cubies, ncubies, 'w', 'r'));
    appendtofc(match3(cubies, ncubies, 'w', 'r' , 'g' ));
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I'd just use `strchr` to emulate `in`. It may be slower, but it's a hell of a lot more readable. (This code doesn't need the optimization anyway, since the strings are of constant length 6).

Comment: Of course one *can* use `strchr`, but these short loops are simple, and what could possibly be the point of translating a Python program to C other than maximum speed? And there's no equivalent of `a.count` in C so at least one of the loops is necessary anyway.

Comment: Not convinced using `needc` as a bitfield is valuable here - probably more readable as three booleans - pretty sure that'd be optimized to the same thing anyway.

Comment: @Eric bool instead of bits is a reasonable alternative, and might even be faster (but I can assure you the code won't be identical for any existing compiler).

Comment: @JimBalter, I don't understand what cubes and ncubies should be here? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: cubies is exactly what it is in your Python code -- an array of strings. ncubies in the number of strings in the array, since unlike in Python, C arrays aren't data structures that contain their length. If you don't understand these things, then you are way over your head and should learn a lot more C, and programming in general -- which I don't have the time to teach you.

Comment: @JimBalter, Thanks for being so patient, I understood cubies soon after posting, but the ncubies remained elusive

Answer (score -2):

C has no functional programming. In case you can use C++ instead, I would say the closest is `remove_if` with a lambda expression. Here's a demo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

using std::string;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::list<string> cubies = {"hello", "world", "bar", "baz"};
  cubies.remove_if([](const string& s){
    return s.find("a") != string::npos;
  });

  for (const string& s : cubies) {
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 cubies.cc 
$ ./a.out 
hello
world
```

Comment: -1 for wrong language. C++ is a totally different language from C just as Python is.

Comment: There is no functional equivalent in C. I don't know whether OP really can't use C++ or not.

Comment: Going to have to agree with @Jam Balter :/ sorry mate

Comment: Seriously? The OP asked for an answer in `C` and you're surprised that a `C++` answer isn't welcomed?

Comment: "haters be hatin'" That's ridiculous and dishonest; I program in C and C++; it has nothing to do with hate, only with this site's rules. How the heck did you acquire that mojo without knowing the basics? I'm flagging. You should just delete this.

Comment: How is that dishonest? Are you familiar with [the internet](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/haters-gonna-hate) ?

Comment: @jterrace, sorry about this, I'm hoping you simply misread the tags, otherwise I have admittedly very little sympathy for you

Comment: It's dishonest because this is about you providing an inappropriate answer and being called on it, rather than anything about hating.

Comment: "There is no functional equivalent in C." -- Of course there is ... it's a frigging Turing Machine.

Comment: I originally misread the tag, then edited the question to keep it anyway, for posterity's sake. Many future visitors will probably land on this page after searching google for "C equivalent of Python filter" when they really meant C++. You're welcome to downvote, since it doesn't answer the question, but I'm not going to delete it.

Comment: Well at least stop with the dishonest insults of the people who properly downvoted you.

Comment: @JimBalter C is a procedural language, it does not have any first-class functional support

Comment: Gentlemen, please, there is no reason to argue over the Internet, I'm 15, yet I can see this has developed into a petty argument. Please, shake virtual hands and forgive each other :)

Comment: Who said anything about first-class functional support? The OP wants to implement the Python code in C -- nothing about using lambda expressions. "functional equivalent" does not have anything to do with functions, it's about the program as a whole having the same function in the logical, not programming language, sense.

Comment: Only one person made it petty. By the SO site rules, this is not a proper answer to the question and deserves the downvotes.

Comment: @JimBalter I agree whole heartedly

Comment: The filter function uses the functional programming paradigm. Yes, you can write the procedural paradigm equivalent in C, but C does not have a functional paradigm method of writing an equivalent statement.

Comment: Sigh. A filter function could be written in C that takes a function pointer and a `void*` for context. But that's irrelevant -- the OP wants to translate the Python code to C and doesn't really care about filter or lambda.